# It there possible to detect mosaic which was generated by FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

We are doing some experiments using FFmpeg, however, there might be mosaic in some of section of the transcoded video, like:

[image]

So, I would like to [extract the key frames](https://superuser.com/a/1153483/128711) of the video, and not sure what't the best practice to detect mosaic in this case?

A Google search for `image mosaic detect` yields thousands of papers, I was wondering if there any exists tools?

Comment: Not a typical "mosaic", but looks like improper decoding from a damaged or corrupted frame. Perhaps you can refer to the ffmpeg log with the proper loglevel and it may tell you the timestamp when it encounters such frames. I can't try it myself because I don't have your input file.

Comment: Thanks @llogan , unfortunately we can't fetch the ffmpeg logs, since it's from kind of black-box-supplier, what I can do is to make sure their solution will not have regression like this, by using lots of test cases and extract/verify the key frames.

Comment: I don't understand the situation. So you can run ffmpeg on this black box but are unable to view the console output / log?

Comment: @llogan Yep, it's kind of RPC services from other suppliers, in which case we couldn't fetch their internal logs.